# omxplayer doesn't play audio when streaming

Tags: audio, streaming-video, omxplayer

When I pass a link to `omxplayer` with `youtube-dl` it won't play the audio only the video. Where as playing it locally works as expected.

It doesn't show the usual `Audio codec ac3 channels 6 samplerate 48000 bitspersample 16` when streaming. And to make it more odd, it can stream audio just fine.

I start omxplayer like this:

```
omxplayer `youtube-dl -g <youtube-url>`
```

Comment: please mark your answer as the correct one if that solved your problem ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out streams have no audio by default. I need to explicitly choose a format that includes the audio stream.

```
youtube-dl -F <youtube-url> # print the available formats
omxplayer `youtube-dl -g -f <format_id> <youtube-url>` # play the video
```

Answer (score 5):

Or for simplicity replace "format_id" with "best" (best: Select best quality format represented by single file with video and audio):

```
omxplayer `youtube-dl -g -f best <youtube-url>` # play the video
```

https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#format-selection

Comment: As far as I know `best` is the default, but even explicitely choosing it didn't work for me. Maybe it was/is a bug.

Comment: Using RB Pi 3 without the -f best did not worked.